# PySide/QT QSharedMemory

Tags: qt, pyside, shared-memory

I wanted to prevent multiple instances of application using PySide -- QSystemSemaphore and QSharedMemory, but, as it seems, there is no QSharedMemory in PySide. Is there any other implementation of shared memory in PySide? Or some other way to prevent multiple instances using PySide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a project in existence to help with this very problem. It is call [siding](https://github.com/stendec/siding). Whie you could just use it as is, you could presumably look at the source code to work out how it is done. It appears from [here](https://github.com/stendec/siding/blob/master/siding/singleinstance.py) that it uses either a Windows Mutex or a lock file depending on OS.